# jquery ui dialog using MVC and CRUD

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to implement some jquery ui dialogs, but i can not find any good examples of doing what I want. I am using MVC4 and CRUD. Once I create a record I want to show a jquery dialog to tell the user this has been done, same with edit. Any examples or tutorials appreciated.

It would be nice to have a jquery dialog once the post has been called the db.savechanges() has been success before the redirect to inform user.

a quick example of what ive done.

here's my view

```
@model Models.customer

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>customer</legend>

     @Html.EditorForModel()

  </fieldset>
     <div id="submitCreateButton">
       <input type="submit" value="Create"  />
    </div>

}
<div id="backToListLink">
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index",new { conName = ViewBag.connectionName },   null)
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

and my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(customer customer)
    {

        using (db = new trakman_Entities(staticConnection))
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                customer.code = customer.code.ToUpper();
                db.customers.AddObject(customer);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        return View(customer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ajax options to your form, which calls the dialog, something like this

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new AjaxOptions{OnSuccess = "handleSuccess"}))
 {

 }

 @section scripts {
     <script>
         function handleSuccess(result) {
             //call dialog
         }
     </script>
```